# Will being denied Schengen entry affect my future travel there?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas

On June 5, I arrived at the airport in Frankfurt and intended to fly to my final destination, with an intermediate connection in Vienna. Because of not having a Schengen visa, I wasn't permitted to continue my flights and my passport was stamped as you see below. Fortunately, I was allowed to buy tickets bypassing Schengen zone and reach home. If I had known about the visa requirement beforehand, I never would have bought the tickets that caused so many problems.

What the codes "C" and "I" in the rights below corner of the stamp mean and what are the implications of these codes?

[image]

Comment: what is your nationality and what is your intended destination? Did you have austrian visa?

Comment: You tried to enter the Schengen Area without a valid visa. This will certainly be recorded and will be factored into the decision making process.

Comment: What is unclear about this question?

Comment: @pbu: Austria is a Schengen member, and the OP stated they did not have a Schengen visa.

Comment: How did airlines allow you to board without proper visa?

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't been warned by any agency about visa requirement. The first 2 flights of a 4 leg voyage was within and from a country  in South America that I have a visa for. One of the legs was within Schengen area and I didn't realize that in an international airport I may have a visa problem.

Comment: This is a common question about transit inside Schengen zone.

Comment: Can somebody explain what the codes "C" and "I" in the rights below corner of the stamp mean?

Comment: @Goga Those indicate the reasons for denying you entry. "C" means "no valid visa". "I" is especially bad as it means "considered threat to public security". See http://eur-lex.europa.eu/resource.html?uri=uriserv:OJ.L_.2006.105.01.0001.01.ENG.xhtml.L_2006105EN.01002301.tif.jpg